# Touchegg settings unchangeable

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, touchegg

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my asus zenbook (ux31e), and I like it very much! I tried to find a solution for my multi-touch touchpad, and found touchegg. Installed it via the software center, and I've put it in the start-up programs. All the gestures worked immediately after I rebooted, pretty cool.

Only problem is, whenever I change settings in the touchegg.conf file it gets saved in the config file, but touchegg doesn't seem to copy those settings, and only stays with the defaults even after reboot etc... Am I missing something here?

Regards,

Marty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are applying your changes to the config file located in your home directory.

```
~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

If you don't have any file in this place copy the following file to the path above.

```
/usr/share/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```